# bind data with dropdownlistbox in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter.
I want to bind the column of my table with dropdownlistbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// your controller
function index() {
    $result = $this->your_model->get_list();

    foreach ($result as $country)
    {
        $countries[$country->id] = $country->name;
    }

    $data['countries'] = $countries;
    $this->load->view('your_view', $data);
}

//your model
function get_list() {
   return $this->db->get('countries');
}

// your view
echo form_dropdown('country', $countries);
```

This is practically the easiest way to do this.